# Xcode 9 beta4/5: This app was unable to be installed

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I've been trying to get Firebase working with Auth, Google Sign In and Facebook login, and I'm getting this error every time I try to run it in the simulator:

[image]

Nothing is logged in the console or the simulator log, but when I look in the system console, I find what appears to be the problem:

> 0x70000b260000 -[MIBundle _validateWithError:]: 38: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/derekclarkson/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FF1AC158-D8C6-411E-8912-146C355DC97B/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.SFHCp0/extracted/Crux.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework

How do I fix it?

Comment: Try cleaning Developer >> Derived data and run again. It may work

Comment: yep. tried that :-) still won't install

Comment: Had the same problem, resolved by reinstalling Xcode beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem turned out to be some frameworks I was using. The frameworks (Firebase) looked like normal frameworks so I added a copy file phase to the project to copy them to the Frameworks directory of the app. However they are actually static libraries which look like frameworks so I didn't need to copy them. Because they are static libraries, they don't have a Info.plist file in them and that was causing the failure.

Answer (score 5):

- Delete derived data.
- Clean project command + K.
- Build again.

Answer (score 1):

Removing derived data and changing the simulator worked for me. Previously I was using iPhone 6 another I used iPhone 7.

Answer (score 0):

press: <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> (in xcode)

This will delete all of the products and intermediate files in the build folder.It's different from delete derive data.